# How do do V=(white(2e6*time)/10) noise on voltage source with LTSpice?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I am trying to inject noise into the Voltage Source as shown in [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55233/how-do-you-simulate-voltage-noise-with-ltspice). The `NOISE` function looks like this: `V=(white(2e6*time)/10)`. I am new to LTSpice. How to actually use the `white` function? Where do I go in the LTSpice tool to enter this function?

I can right click on the voltage source and I see this window. Where do I enter the `white` function?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the *behavioral voltage source* and apply the white() function there. Hit F2, then look for "bv" as the item in the dialog box. Drop that puppy down on the schematic. Do *NOT* use the regular voltage source for this.

Comment: @user1406716 I'm glad that helped!

Comment: If you can, use the `BI`, or `BI2`, which would save you one node in the matrix solver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a voltage noise source and/or current noise source for use with LTspice you can download such noise sources on my GitHub page https://github.com/yildi1337/LTspiceNoiseSources.

Below you can find screenshots of two examples:

[image: Example with voltage noise source]
[image: Example with current noise source]

Comment: I see you keep on answering with this on several questions, please don't spam. Besides, this is about `.TRAN`, not `.NOISE`.

Comment: I haven't used the sources in a time-domain simulation (.TRAN) yet. But they are working fine in a .NOISE simulation.