# Can LTSpice waveforms be exported for further processing?

Tags: ltspice, signal-processing

The following LTSpice temporal domain output is taken from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/55256/56469. Thanks @Oli.

Is it possible to acquire the underlying data that generated V(noise+sig) as a table/file of data points for further processing? Some sort of export function perchance?

[image: graph]

Comment: Hard to believe you did the background research on your own here when the "Export data as text" is plainly visible in the _File_ menu, not even hidden in a submenu. There's even an entry in the F.A.Q. named "Exporting Waveform Data".

Comment: @pipe And yet Mr. Spike gets the points for being very helpful...

Comment: @pipe How hard do you think it is to implement a downvote for lazyness in SE? I am preemptively giving it my dfull support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the plot and then export data as text.

You can then pick which nodes you want to export and the file name
[image]

If you want to export V(noise+sig) then create a b-source with

```
V=V(noise+sig)
```

[image]
then record the output of the b-source node in the file  (you could even label the output node as Vnoiseandsig, so you know what it is in the file)

Another useful thing to know is that you can export data and then reimport it in a PWL file, which is useful for comparing simulations if the comparison can't be done in any other manner:

https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-importing-exporting-pwl-data.html